# Save a excel file in symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony, export-to-excel

Using `$this->render('Bundle:Controller:View', [$MyDoctrineQueryResult])` I have sent a doctrine query result to a twig view which creates a report. Now I have to give the client the option to export such report to Excel. I have the code to do such thing already working but I haven't find out a way to send the $MyDoctrineQueryResult array from the twig view to the controller that have the Export to Excel code. Please any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Controller should be responsible for that. You shouldn't all the data from view to controllsender.

Comment: I'm sorry ... I shouldn't what ?

Comment: You shouldn't send the same data from the view to the controller to generate the excel... Just fetch the same query result in your controller action (with same controller parameters as with creating the normal view) that generates the excel - or if you prefer, store the query result in session and fetch it from there in the excel generation.